# JavaFX MouseTransparent stage

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make a JavaFX application that will pass all the mouse events through itself (just like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irUQGDDSk_g, but in Java) How can I make the stage **Mouse-Transparent**?